# How to detect the device on React SSR App with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, device-detection

on a web application I want to display two different Menu, one for the Mobile, one for the Desktop browser.
I use Next.js application with server-side rendering and the library [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect).

Here is the [CodeSandox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/affectionate-meadow-9uhez?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { BrowserView, MobileView } from "react-device-detect";

export default () => (
  <div>
    Hello World.{" "}
    <Link href="/about">
      <a>About</a>
    </Link>
    <BrowserView>
      <h1> This is rendered only in browser </h1>
    </BrowserView>
    <MobileView>
      <h1> This is rendered only on mobile </h1>
    </MobileView>
  </div>
);
```

If you open this in a browser and **switch to mobile** view and look the console you get this error:

> Warning: Text content did not match. Server: " This is rendered only
>   in browser " Client: " This is rendered only on mobile "

This happen because the rendering by the server detects a browser and on the client, he is a mobile device. The only workaround I found is to generate both and use the CSS like this:

```
.activeOnMobile {
  @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.activeOnDesktop {
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Instead of the library but I don't really like this method. Does someone know the good practice to handle devices type on an SSR app directly in the react code?

Comment: I think there is no solution for that atm because rendering at server side then browser information is agnostic and it also relates to cache time of your html response

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**LATEST UPDATE:**

So if you don't mind doing it client side you can use the dynamic importing as suggested by a few people below. This will be for use cases where you use static page generation.

i created a component which passes all the `react-device-detect` exports as props (it would be wise to filter out only the needed exports because then does not treeshake)

```js
// Device/Device.tsx

import { ReactNode } from 'react'
import * as rdd from 'react-device-detect'

interface DeviceProps {
  children: (props: typeof rdd) => ReactNode
}
export default function Device(props: DeviceProps) {
  return <div className="device-layout-component">{props.children(rdd)}</div>
}
```

```js
// Device/index.ts

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Device = dynamic(() => import('./Device'), { ssr: false })

export default Device
```

and then when you want to make use of the component you can just do

```
const Example = () => {
  return (
    <Device>
      {({ isMobile }) => {
        if (isMobile) return <div>My Mobile View</div>
        return <div>My Desktop View</div>
      }}
    </Device>
  )
}
```

---

Personally I just use a hook to do this, although the initial props method is better.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const getMobileDetect = (userAgent: NavigatorID['userAgent']) => {
  const isAndroid = () => Boolean(userAgent.match(/Android/i))
  const isIos = () => Boolean(userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i))
  const isOpera = () => Boolean(userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i))
  const isWindows = () => Boolean(userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i))
  const isSSR = () => Boolean(userAgent.match(/SSR/i))
  const isMobile = () => Boolean(isAndroid() || isIos() || isOpera() || isWindows())
  const isDesktop = () => Boolean(!isMobile() && !isSSR())
  return {
    isMobile,
    isDesktop,
    isAndroid,
    isIos,
    isSSR,
  }
}
const useMobileDetect = () => {
  useEffect(() => {}, [])
  const userAgent = typeof navigator === 'undefined' ? 'SSR' : navigator.userAgent
  return getMobileDetect(userAgent)
}

export default useMobileDetect
```

I had the problem that scroll animation was annoying on mobile devices so I made a device based enabled scroll animation component;

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
import ScrollAnimation, { ScrollAnimationProps } from 'react-animate-on-scroll'
import useMobileDetect from 'src/utils/useMobileDetect'

interface DeviceScrollAnimation extends ScrollAnimationProps {
  device: 'mobile' | 'desktop'
  children: ReactNode
}

export default function DeviceScrollAnimation({ device, animateIn, animateOut, initiallyVisible, ...props }: DeviceScrollAnimation) {
  const currentDevice = useMobileDetect()

  const flag = device === 'mobile' ? currentDevice.isMobile() : device === 'desktop' ? currentDevice.isDesktop() : true

  return (
    <ScrollAnimation
      animateIn={flag ? animateIn : 'none'}
      animateOut={flag ? animateOut : 'none'}
      initiallyVisible={flag ? initiallyVisible : true}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

UPDATE:

so after further going down the rabbit hole, the best solution i came up with is using the react-device-detect in a useEffect, if you further inspect the device detect you will notice that it exports const's that are set via the `ua-parser-js` lib

```js
export const UA = new UAParser();

export const browser = UA.getBrowser();
export const cpu = UA.getCPU();
export const device = UA.getDevice();
export const engine = UA.getEngine();
export const os = UA.getOS();
export const ua = UA.getUA();
export const setUA = (uaStr) => UA.setUA(uaStr);
```

This results in the initial device being the server which causes false detection.

I forked the repo and created and added a [ssr-selector](https://github.com/PaulPCIO/react-device-detect/tree/ssr-selectors) which requires you to pass in a user-agent. which could be done using the initial props

UPDATE:

Because of Ipads not giving a correct or rather well enough defined user-agent, see this [issue](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119186), I decided to create a hook to better detect the device

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function isTouchDevice() {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return false
  const prefixes = ' -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- '.split(' ')
  function mq(query) {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.matchMedia(query).matches
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  if ('ontouchstart' in window || (window?.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) return true
  const query = ['(', prefixes.join('touch-enabled),('), 'heartz', ')'].join('') // include the 'heartz' - https://git.io/vznFH
  return mq(query)
}

export default function useIsTouchDevice() {
  const [isTouch, setIsTouch] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const { isAndroid, isIPad13, isIPhone13, isWinPhone, isMobileSafari, isTablet } = require('react-device-detect')
    setIsTouch(isTouch || isAndroid || isIPad13 || isIPhone13 || isWinPhone || isMobileSafari || isTablet || isTouchDevice())
  }, [])

  return isTouch
```

Because I require the package each time I call that hook, the UA info is updated, it also fixes to SSR out of sync warnings.

Comment: I think this should be changed to `if ('ontouchstart' in window || (window?.Document && document instanceof Document)) return true;`. Not 100% sure, but TS complains about it, and there's also [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentTouch)

Comment: Ah I see, this breaks the package. I temporarily added `interface Window { DocumentTouch: any; }` to my `global.d.ts`. This works for now: `if ('ontouchstart' in window || (window?.DocumentTouch && document instanceof Document)) return true;`

Comment: I have tried both `react-device-detect` and `is-mobile`. None of them works in landscape mode!

Answer (score 38):

I think you should do it by using getInitialProps in your page, as it runs both on the server and on the client, and getting the device type by first detecting if you are just getting the request for the webpage (so you are still on the server), or if you are re-rendering (so you are on the client).

```
// index.js

IndexPage.getInitialProps = ({ req }) => {
  let userAgent;
  if (req) { // if you are on the server and you get a 'req' property from your context
    userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'] // get the user-agent from the headers
  } else {
    userAgent = navigator.userAgent // if you are on the client you can access the navigator from the window object
  }
}
```

Now you can use a regex to see if the device is a mobile or a desktop.

```
// still in getInitialProps

let isMobile = Boolean(userAgent.match(
  /Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile|WPDesktop/i
))

return { isMobile }
```

Now you can access the isMobile prop that will return either true or false

```
const IndexPage = ({ isMobile }) => {
  return ( 
    <div>
     {isMobile ? (<h1>I am on mobile!</h1>) : (<h1>I am on desktop! </h1>)} 
    </div>
  )
}
```

I got this answer from [this article here](https://medium.com/100-articles-marathon/getting-device-type-in-next-js-e8c3534ca421)
I hope that was helpful to you

**UPDATE**

Since Next 9.5.0, `getInitialProps` is going to be replaced by `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`. While `getStaticProps` is for fetching static data, which will be used to create an html page at build time, `getServerSideProps` generates the page dynamically on each request, and receives the `context` object with the `req` prop just like `getInitialProps`. The difference is that `getServerSideProps` is not going to know `navigator`, because it is only server side. The usage is also a little bit different, as you have to export an async function, and not declare a method on the component. It would work this way:

```
const HomePage = ({ deviceType }) => {
let componentToRender
  if (deviceType === 'mobile') {
    componentToRender = <MobileComponent />
  } else {
    componentToRender = <DesktopComponent />
  }

  return componentToRender
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const UA = context.req.headers['user-agent'];
  const isMobile = Boolean(UA.match(
    /Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile|WPDesktop/i
  ))
  
  return {
    props: {
      deviceType: isMobile ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'
    }
  }
}


export default HomePage
```

Please note that since `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` are mutually exclusive, you would need to give up the SSG advantages given by `getStaticProps` in order to know the device type of the user. I would suggest not to use getServerSideProps for this purpose if you need just to handle a couple of styiling details. If the structure of the page is much different depending on the device type than maybe it is worth it

Comment: Thank you, I go test it

Comment: Hi Dylanbob211, what is the way to get `isMobile` props from any components?

Comment: Well, you have this prop in your page component (index.js or whatever page component where the getInitialProp function is in), so you need to pass the prop. You can do it with the prop-drilling technique (the classing prop passing from parent to children), with a state manager (redux, mobx etc.) or using the Context API. The thing is that you get this prop only in a page component, because you need to use getInitialProps

Comment: Remember that the `navigator` will never be defined in the `getInitialProps`, the `getInitialProps` only runs server-side, so you will always receive the `req.headers['user-agent']`

Comment: you could still apply the `getInitialProps` method using the _app.js and then just pass it down to your pages as a prop.

Comment: It's too bad we can't out of the box have "cache policies" with ISR so that a single /page/:foo where https://example.com/foo can generate N number of caches.

For instance, Cloudfront CDN can pass to origin "Is-[Desktop,Mobile,Tablet]-Viewer=bool" headers. Would be great to easily map those headers to "pageCacheKeys".

Comment: You should use `middleware` for getStaticProps

Answer (score 7):

`react-device-detect` now offers a `getSelectorsByUserAgent` you can use server-side and you need to pass the user-agent as an argument. If you are using app router in next.js, you can get the user-agent from the headers.

[reference](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect/blob/44d68ccd26e4b3b73adce2744f2d745bae2d42f3/docs/api.md#utils--ssr)

```
// index.tsx
import { headers } from "next/headers"
import { getSelectorsByUserAgent } from "react-device-detect"
import MobileVersion from "./mobile"
import BrowserVersion from "./browser"

export default function SomeComponent() {
  // you can get more than just isMobile from this.
  const { isMobile } = getSelectorsByUserAgent(
    headers().get("user-agent") ?? ""
  )

  return isMobile ? <Mobile /> : <Browser />
}
```

```
//mobile.tsx
export default () => <div>this is the mobile version</div>
```

```
//browser.tsx
export default () => <div>this is the browser version</div>
```

Comment: Only thing that worked for me with Nextjs 13.

Comment: Notice that using `headers()` would [cause dynamic rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers#headers), and that would be [the whole route](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#switching-to-dynamic-rendering), so maybe some [Parallel Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes) for other parts would become more necessary.

Answer (score 5):

#### Load only the JS files needed dynamically

You can load components dynamically with next/dynamic, and only the appropriate component will be loaded.

You can use react-detect-device or is-mobile and in my case. In this scenario, I created separate layout for mobile and desktop, and load the appropriate component base on device.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const mobile = require('is-mobile');

const ShowMobile = dynamic(() => mobile() ? import('./ShowMobile.mobile') : import('./ShowMobile'), { ssr: false })


const TestPage = () => {

   return <ShowMobile />
}

export default TestPage
```

You can view the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wood-bp886?file=/src/App.js) . Only the required component.JS will be loaded.

Edit:

How different is the above from conditionally loading component? e.g.

```
isMobile ? <MobileComponent /> : <NonMobileComponent />
```

The first solution will not load the JS file, while in second solution, both JS files will be loaded. So you save one round trip.

Answer (score 4):

With current Next.js (v 9.5+) I accomplished that using `next/dynamic` and `react-detect-device`.

For instance, on my `header` component:

```
...
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
...

const MobileMenuHandler = dynamic(() => import('./mobileMenuHandler'), {
 ssr: false,
});

return (
...
    <MobileMenuHandler
        isMobileMenuOpen={isMobileMenuOpen}
        setIsMobileMenuOpen={setIsMobileMenuOpen}
    />
)
...
```

Then on `MobileMenuHandler`, which is only called on the client:

```
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';
...
return(
   {isMobile && !isMobileMenuOpen ? (
       <Menu
          onClick={() => setIsMobileMenuOpen(true)}
          className={classes.menuIcon}
       />
   ) : null}
)
```

With that, the `react-detect-device` is only active on the client side and can give a proper reading.

See [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to resolve with react-device-detect.

```
    export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
    const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'] || '';
    const { isMobile } = getSelectorsByUserAgent(userAgent);

    return {
        props: { isMobile },
    };
}
```

you can find more keys below because it is not specified on type definition of react-device-detect lib.

```
{
  isSmartTV: false,
  isConsole: false,
  isWearable: false,
  isEmbedded: false,
  isMobileSafari: false,
  isChromium: false,
  isMobile: false,
  isMobileOnly: false,
  isTablet: false,
  isBrowser: true,
  isDesktop: true,
  isAndroid: false,
  isWinPhone: false,
  isIOS: false,
  isChrome: true,
  isFirefox: false,
  isSafari: false,
  isOpera: false,
  isIE: false,
  osVersion: '10.15.7',
  osName: 'Mac OS',
  fullBrowserVersion: '107.0.0.0',
  browserVersion: '107',
  browserName: 'Chrome',
  mobileVendor: 'none',
  mobileModel: 'none',
  engineName: 'Blink',
  engineVersion: '107.0.0.0',
  getUA: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  isEdge: false,
  isYandex: false,
  deviceType: 'browser',
  isIOS13: false,
  isIPad13: false,
  isIPhone13: false,
  isIPod13: false,
  isElectron: false,
  isEdgeChromium: false,
  isLegacyEdge: false,
  isWindows: false,
  isMacOs: true,
  isMIUI: false,
  isSamsungBrowser: false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was able to avoid dynamic importing or component props, by using React state instead. For my use case, I was trying to detect if it was Safari, but this can work for other ones as well.

Import code

```js
import { browserName } from 'react-device-detect';
```

Component code

```
const [isSafari, setIsSafari] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsSafari(browserName === 'Safari');
}, [browserName]);

// Then respect the state in the render
return <div data-is-safari={isSafari} />;
```

Answer (score 2):

When I was working on one of my next.js projects, I came across a similar situation. I have got some ideas from the answers. And I did solve it with the following approach.

Firstly, I made custom hook using `react-device-detect`

```
//hooks/useDevice.ts
import { isDesktop, isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';

interface DeviceDetection {
  isMobile: boolean;
  isDesktop: boolean;
}

const useDevice = (): DeviceDetection => ({
  isMobile,
  isDesktop
});

export default useDevice;
```

Secondly, I made a component which uses of custom hook

```
//Device/Device.tsx
import { ReactElement } from 'react';

import useDevice from '@/hooks/useDevice';

export interface DeviceProps {
  desktop?: boolean;
  mobile?: boolean;
  children: ReactElement;
}

export const Device = ({ desktop, mobile, children }: DeviceProps): ReactElement | null => {
  const { isMobile } = useDevice();

  return (isMobile && mobile) || (!isMobile && desktop) ? children : null;
};
```

Thirdly, I import the component dynamically using next.js `next/dynamic`

```
//Device/index.tsx
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
    
import type { DeviceProps } from './Device';
    
export const Device = dynamic<DeviceProps>(() => import('./Device').then((mod) => mod.Device), {
      ssr: false
    });
```

Finally, I used it following way in pages.

```
//pages/my-page.tsx
import { Device } from '@/components/Device';
<Device desktop>
    <my-component>Desktop</my-component>
 </Device>
<Device mobile>
    <my-component>Mobile</my-component>
 </Device>
```

Answer (score 2):

for ssr just use

```
import {headers} from 'next/headers';
const layout = ({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const headersList = headers()
    const isMobile = isMobileUserAgent(headersList.get('user-agent'))
```

and function is:

```
export const isMobileUserAgent = (userAgent) => {
    return /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(userAgent);
};
```

Comment: it works in NextJS ^13

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with user-agent information in `nextjs` from server side you'll have to use `getServerSide` props. because this is the only function that has access to req object. `getStaticProps` is not helpful.

First create a helper function just to reuse on several pages.

```
const getDevice = (userAgent) => {
let device = "";

if(userAgent && userAgent !== ""){
    let isMobile = userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile|WPDesktop/i)
    if(isMobile && isMobile?.length > 0){
        device = "mobile";
    }
}

return device 
}
```

You can further modify above function as per your need.

Now in your getServerSideProps:

```
export const getServerSideProps = ({req}) => {
   const device = getDevice(req.headers['user-agent']);
   
   return {
      props: {
         device,
      }
   }
}
```

Now you have device information in your page. You can use to render different totally different layouts just like flipkart and olx.

NOTE : Changes will only reflect when a fresh page will be requested because server does not aware of client changes in viewport. If you want such thing probably you can use context api.

**The downside is : You have to make each page that shifts layout, a server rendered page.**

However if you are going to deploy your nextjs on netlify consider using `middlewares` with combination of `@netlify/next` package. More info [here](https://www.netlify.com/blog/rewrite-html-transform-page-props-in-nextjs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind rendering always desktop version and figuring the logic on the front-end, then the hook logic can be pretty straightforward.

```js
export const useDevice = () => {
  const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => { setFirstLoad(false); }, []);

  const ssr = firstLoad || typeof navigator === "undefined";

  const isAndroid = !ssr && /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  const isIos = !ssr && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;

  return {
    isAndroid,
    isIos,
    isDesktop: !isAndroid && !isIos
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect'

...


const [_isMobile, setMobile] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setMobile(isMobile);
    }, [setMobile]);

<div hidden={_isMobile}> Desktop View</div>

<div hidden={!_isMobile}> MobileView </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a case like this using `next-useragent`.

```
const mobileBreakpoint = 1280;
/**
 * 
 * @param userAgent - the UserAgent object from `next-useragent`
 */
export const useIsMobile = (userAgent?: UserAgent): boolean => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);
  // Some front-end hook that gets the current breakpoint, but returns undefined, if we don't have a window object.
  const { breakpoint } = useResponsive();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (breakpoint) {
      setIsMobile(breakpoint.start < mobileBreakpoint);
    }
    else if (userAgent) {
      setIsMobile(userAgent.isMobile);
    } else if (!isBrowser) {
      setIsMobile(false);
    }
  }, [userAgent, breakpoint]);
  return isMobile;
};
```

And the usage of it is:

```
// Inside react function component.
const isMobile = useIsMobile(props.userAgent);
```

```
export const getServerSideProps = (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext,
): GetServerSidePropsResult<{ userAgent?: UserAgent }> => ({
  // Add the user agent to the props, so we can use it in the window hook.
  props: {
    userAgent: parse(context.req.headers["user-agent"] ?? ""),
  },
});
```

This hook always returns a boolean `isMobile`. When you run it server-side, it uses the user-agent header to detect a mobile device in the SSR request. When this gets to client side, it uses the breakpoints (in my case), or any other logic for width detection to update the boolean. You could use `next-useragent` to also detect the specific device type, but you can't make resolution-based rendering server-side.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to fix this is to use something like the NoSsr component from MUI.

For example

```
{ isMobile &&
   <NoSsr>
    <ComponentYouWantToRenderInMobile />
   </NoSsr>
}
```

That will stop the error from appearing.

So in OPs case:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { BrowserView, MobileView } from "react-device-detect";
import { NoSsr } from "@mui/material";

export default () => (
  <div>
    Hello World.{" "}
    <Link href="/about">
      <a>About</a>
    </Link>
    <NoSsr>
      <BrowserView>
        <h1> This is rendered only in browser </h1>
      </BrowserView>
      <MobileView>
        <h1> This is rendered only on mobile </h1>
      </MobileView>
     </ NoSsr>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This always works. (I used this package after trying the above technique and it didn't work for me.)

The advantage: The component renders server side so there's no flashing on client side when trying to detect user agent.

```
import { isMobile } from "mobile-device-detect";
```

just import the package and create your layout.

```
import { isMobile } from "mobile-device-detect";

const Desktop = () => {
  return (
    <>
      desktop
    </>
  );
};

Desktop.layout = Layout;

const Mobile = () => {
  return (
    <>
      mobile
    </>
  );
};

Mobile.layout = LayoutMobile;

const Page = isMobile ? Desktop : Mobile;

export default Page;
```